# Give an example of a cover for $\Bbb R$ that isn't locally finite, but has the property that every $x \in \Bbb R$ belongs to only finitely many covers

Tags: general-topology

> Give an example of a cover for $\Bbb R$ that isn't locally finite, but has the property that every $x \in \Bbb R$ belongs to only finitely many covers.

We may assume that $\Bbb R$ has the standard topology. A class $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ of subsets of a topological space $X$ is locally finite if for every $x \in X$, there exists $O_x$ such that $O_x \cap U_i \ne \emptyset$ for finitely many $i$.

Is the question poorly stated or am I not understanding it properly? What do they mean by "finitely many *covers*"? As stated it makes very little sense to me. By *covers* do they mean the elements of the collection that covers $\Bbb R$ or what?

Answer (score 1):

The question is worded a little strangely. I think that by "belongs to only finitely many covers" they mean that for the open cover $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$, for each $x$ there are only finitely many $i$ such that $x \in U_i$. By "covers", I think they mean elements of the set $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$.

My idea for a cover that satisfies the given constraints is as follows. For $i\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, let $$U_i = (\sum_{j=1}^i2^{-j}-\delta_i, \sum_{j=1}^{i+1}2^{-j}-\delta_i)$$
Where $\delta_i$ is a very small number such that each interval overlaps the intervals directly adjacent to it (something like $\delta_i=100^{-i}$).

Then, let $U_{-1}=(1,\infty)$ and $U_{-2}=(-\infty,0)$. The collection $\{U_i\}_{i\geq-2}$ forms an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, each $x$ lies in at most 2 of the intervals. However, any neighborhood of $x=1$ intersects with infinitely many intervals in the open cover. So, $\{U_i\}_{i\geq -2}$ is not locally finite.

Let me know your thoughts or if anyone can think of a simpler cover that does the trick!

Comment: This may be simpler $U_n = (1/n,2/n)$. $U_0 = (-\infty, 1)$, $U_{-1} = (-1, \infty)$.  These cover the real line.  If $x \in U_n$ for infinitely many $n$, then $1/n < x < 2/n$ for infinitely many $n$ and so $x = 0$, a contradiction.  Nonetheless, every neighborhood of $0$ intersects infinitely many $U_n$.